# Generating unique identity column value across different SQL Server instances

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, identity-column

I have WinForm application (C#) and Backed as SQL Server 2008, which works offline at client location. Currently all branches were getting managed from single location, so an identity column value is always unique across branches.

Now, I want this application to be managed from multiple locations and should work offline as well as online. To make it possible we are putting a SQL Server in PUBLIC IP and each branch will have a separate local SQL Server instance running. The data wil be synced between local and central sever on regular intervals.

Is this approach good to sync data, or is there something better that I can do?

If I go with above approach the problem that I will face is in syncing the data. There is a problem with table structure, eg. I have a table COURSES as follows:

```
COURSES ( COURSE_ID (identity column), COURSE_NAME, COURSE_BRANCH_ID)
```

where

1. `COURSE_ID` is an IDENTITY column
2. `COURSE_NAME` represents the name of Standard
3. `COURSE_BRANCH_ID` represents the branch, where the course is taken.

Now each SQL Server will generate its own value for the `COURSE_ID` column and that might be same for different server.

1. The unique combination is `COURSE_ID` and `COURSE_BRANCH_ID`.
2. Is there any way I can a append `COURSE_BRANCH_ID` with `COURSE_ID` without adding a new IDENTITY column?

Approach I thought of

1. Remove identity from `COURSE_ID` column,
2. Add a new column say ID which will be a identity column.
3. Now after insert on COURCES table write a trigger which will update the value of `COURSE_ID` as `Concate(COURSE_BRANCH_ID,ID)`

```sql
 convert(number(convert(varchar,COURSE_BRANCH_ID) + convert(varchar,ID))
```

But this will require lots of efforts as I have around 19 tables with such problem. I there any thing better than this we can do? Any suggestions are welcome! Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

There are several approaches related to this issue. The one you mentioned where you concatenate the branch id to the identity field.

You can use GUID, the possibility of collision is almost zero. 
Or you can set the Identity Seed and Increment, such that each branch has a different start value, and all incremented by the number of branches.

For example, if you have four branches, then on Branch1 you may set the

```
ID INT IDENTITY(1, 4) NOT NULL -- IDs will be 1, 5, 9...etc.
```

On Branch2

```
ID INT IDENTITY(2, 4) NOT NULL -- IDs will be 2, 6, 10 ...etc
```

On Branch3

```
ID INT IDENTITY(3, 4) NOT NULL -- IDs will be 3, 7, 11 ...etc
```

And on Branch4

```
ID INT IDENTITY(4, 4) NOT NULL -- IDs will be 4, 8, 12 ...etc.
```